# Convergence of sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Let's say I have $2n-1$ coefficients $p_1,...,p_{2n-1}$, which satisfy the following sums for $n>1$

$$
\left\{
    \begin{split}
        \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}p_k&=0\\
        \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{p_k}{1+k}&=\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\\
        \sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{kp_k}{1+k}&=-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}
    \end{split}
    \right.
$$

Finding all $p_k$ seems not possible given to few equations, but is there a way to find the series

$$
f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{2n-1}\frac{p_k}{k+x}=?
$$

For small $n$ I know the solutions to be:

$$
\begin{split}
        f_1(\Lambda)&=\frac{1}{1+\Lambda}\\
        f_2(\Lambda)&=\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{1+\Lambda}-\frac{2}{2+\Lambda}+\frac{\frac{2}{3}}{3+\Lambda}\\
        f_3(\Lambda)&=\frac{2}{1+\Lambda}-\frac{\frac{23}{3}}{2+\Lambda}+\frac{11}{3+\Lambda}-\frac{\frac{20}{3}}{4+\Lambda}+\frac{\frac{4}{3}}{5+\Lambda}\\
        f_4(\Lambda)&=\frac{\frac{28}{15}}{1+\Lambda}-\frac{\frac{72}{5}}{2+\Lambda}+\frac{\frac{236}{5}}{3+\Lambda}-\frac{\frac{230}{5}}{4+\Lambda}+\frac{\frac{318}{5}}{5+\Lambda}-\frac{\frac{126}{5}}{6+\Lambda}+\frac{\frac{18}{5}}{7+\Lambda}
    \end{split}
$$

Does anyone know if these numbers obey some series expansion of a known function?
I appreciate any help!

Comment: You have two independent linear equations (the first one is implied by the second and third) in $2n-1$ variables; the set of solutions will be $(2n-3)$-dimensional (you can choose any values you want for $p_1,\dots,p_{2n-3}$, and then the values for $p_{2n-2}$ and $p_{2n-1}$ will be uniquely determined). In short, there are many different possibilities once $n\ge3$—in particular, your $f_3$ and $f_4$ are not unique.

Comment: @GregMartin Indeed you're right. The equations I have I wrote down knowing $f_1(x)..f_4(x)$ so I know they are exact, maybe one can find more equations from the given set of known solutions to find the sum in question